# Persisting dates RoR/AR to object after instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

using Rails 5 on a personal project. I have a User model with the following AR 
[user schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTRHF.png)

But after attempting to add a return and departure attribute in one of my controllers I get a rollback transaction where it won't let me persist my data to the object. Here is what the controller looks like:

```
def find_flights
   @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
   @user.budget= params["user"]["budget"].to_f
   @user.departure = params["user"]["departure"]
   @user.return = params["user"]["return"]
   @user.save
```

...

and at this point in time the params are as follows:

```
[1] pry(#<QuotesController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"budget"=>"1200", "city"=>"Boston", "departure"=>"09/21/2016", "return"=>"10/08/2016"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Find Flights", "controller"=>"quotes", "action"=>"find_flights"} permitted: false>
```

Even in the Rails console I cannot manually create an object. Note: I do not require the departure/return on instantiation.

Here is my AR error:

```
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" =     ? AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Mark"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

(0.1ms)  rollback transaction

this is the User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :itineraries
  has_many :quotes, through: :itineraries
  validates :name, presence: { message: "must exist" }, uniqueness: { message: "already exists"}
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validate :name_is_alpha_num?

  def name_is_alpha_num?
    if !self.name.match(/^[[:alnum:]]+$/)
    errors.add(:name, "may only be alphanumeric characters")
   end
  end

 def dates_valid?
   dates_not_nil && return_after_departure && dates_in_future
 end

 def return_after_departure
    self.return > self.departure
 end

 def dates_in_future
   (self.return.to_s > Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) && (self.departure.to_s > Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
  end

 def dates_not_nil
    (self.return != nil) && (self.departure != nil)
 end

 def budget_valid?
   budget_not_zero && budget_positive && budget_a_number ? true : false
 end

 def budget_not_zero
    self.budget != 0 && self.budget != nil
  end

 def budget_positive
    self.budget > 0
 end

 def budget_a_number
    self.budget.is_a?(Integer) || self.budget.is_a?(Float)
 end

end
```

Comment: Please can you post the exact error message you are seeing? Also post the code for the users model - the table is not enough to know exactly what is going on here. You are then more likely to get some helpful responses, thanks.

Comment: Done. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: by the way 'return' is a ruby reserved word, not a good idea to use it as a field name, better to say "return_flight" (and "departure_flight" to be consistent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with your model, but now that I see the error message it is telling you "USER EXISTS".

You are trying to create a new user, but that user already exists.

It seems you are storing the id of the user in the session, hence:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

I think you want to UPDATE this user, not SAVE this user.

Read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) in the official guide.

You are calling Save, which will fire your validations. You have a validation that insists the name is unique. Since that user already exists, you cannot use Save. You need to do an update.

Comment: thank you! also realized that the API has different date formatting than the datetime attribute on my user model which had a different format than the datepicker gem...woof... so I had to fix that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah miss-matchted date formats, the bane of our (developer) lives! lol Glad to hear you got your problem resolved.